# Removing a AAAA record - is this safe to do?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

For our domain we currently have both A and AAAA records configured.

We would like to switch the IP to which these records point to. For this purpose, we have purchased a *'dynamic IP'* service from our hosting provider, which provides an additional IP address which is sort of an alias for a target IP address. The 'dynamic IP' is configured on the DNS records and is stable and the target IP can be changed rapidly. The goal of this is to be able to quickly switch out the target IP without incurring the lag that a change of IP in the DNS records would produce.

Thing is, this only works for IPv4 addresses, so with the IPv6 we still have the problem of the long update time should the change the target IP (e.g. because we're switching servers). Our hosting provider does not offer a similar solution for IPv6 addresses.

Our hosting provider suggested that we just delete the AAAA record, but is this a safe thing to do? Will all users find the service afterwards, even if their networks rely on IPv6 internally? We specifically configured the AAAA record in the past because some users hat problems accessing the site and our best guestimate was that it was due to a missing AAAA record (problem stopped after we configured the AAAA record).

Comment: If the 'update time' is an issue, have you considered setting a lower TTL on your AAAA records? Removing them will mean no more IPv6 connections, which does not necessarily sound like what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On v6 networks where neither dual-stack nor NAT64 is in play, clients would not be able to reach your service without an AAAA record.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Is it possible to say in general how common such networks are?

Comment: I don't have solid numbers, though I believe they're fairly rare. Developing markets may be more strongly IPv6-only.

Comment: ...that said, disabling IPv6 is not a good solution. You should perhaps consider a different technique to do what you're doing with the IP address redirect thing, as that sounds quite hacky and is obviously poorly supported if they're asking you to disable your AAAA record.

Comment: Thank you. What do people commonly do here? For our current task, adding a load balancer seems a bit overkill (though that would certainly get the job done)...

Comment: They add a load balancer. :)

Comment: @Paul And it sounds like you already have a significant fraction of users who may be affected if you disable IPv6. Of course this number will only grow as time passes. As for what you should do, it's hard to say, since you haven't really said anything about your application or architecture. But adding a load balancer is certainly a good start.